# DotSpatial problems with reprojecting shapefiles

Tags: c#, wgs84, dotspatial

I have a shapefile with this projection:

```
PROJCS["RD_New",GEOGCS["GCS_Amersfoort",DATUM["D_Amersfoort",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199432955]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",155000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",463000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",5.38763888888889],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999079],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",52.15616055555555],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Now I want to reproject the shapefile to lat/lng coordinates.

I tried:

```
Shapefile tmpShape = Shapefile.OpenFile(file);    
tmpShape.Reproject(KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984);
```

The lat/lng area of the shapefile should be something like 52,.../4,... .
But after reprojecting the file with DotSpatial, I got something like -37,.../23,...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: No idea, but you could try querying tmpShape's coordinate system to see if the software is interpreting it correctly. The wkt is Esri's version; it's possible that dotSpatial is able to read it completely.

Comment: I left out a very important "not" there, as in "not able to read it completely."

Comment: I dont know what exactly do you mean. The tmpShape.ProjectionString is " +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +k_0=0.9999079 +lat_0=52.156160555555552 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +proj=sterea +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-83920.3484091603,72343.8075715773,-385786.84069442,3081200 +ellps=bessel +no_defs"

Comment: Thanks for posting the PROJ.4 string. I think the +towgs84 is wrong. The 4th - 6th values should be in arc-seconds and the 7th in parts per million. Here's what they should be: -0.40685733, 0.35073268, -1.87034738, and 4.0812.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is the best way to change the string? Should I change the .prj file or after open the file in c#?

Comment: Well, the original prj files doesn't have the transformation info, so dotSpatial must be identifying the prj wkt as equivalent to the defn you posted. I think you'll have to modify the tmpShape.ProjectionString. You might check for a resource file and see if you can identify the bad entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an Esri coordinate reference system prj file (well-known text aka WKT), for RD New, DotSpatial is able to map it to a PROJ.4 string. RD New has an EPSG well-known ID of 28992.

DotSpatial includes a +towgs84 parameter which is not part of the original wkt:

```
+towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-83920.3484091603,72343.8075715773,-385786.840‌​69442,3081200
```

The values are supposed to be for a Position Vector-based 7 parameter datum transformation where the seven values are:

```
x axis translation (meters) 
y axis translation (meters) 
z axis translation (meters) 
x axis rotation (arc-seconds) 
y axis rotation (arc-seconds) 
z axis rotation (arc-seconds) 
scale difference (parts per million)
```

The original definition in the [EPSG dataset](http://www.epsg-registry.org) gives the rotations in micro-radians. I wondered how on earth they managed to get such large rotation values. If I convert the original micro-radian value of the x axis rotation, 1.9725, to arc-seconds, I get:

```
0.40685733
```

If I then treat this value as radians, I get:

```
83920.34841 = 0.40685733 * (180.0 / PI) * 3600
```

I can sort of see what they did to the scale difference value, but haven't worked out the math. The original value is 4.0812 ppm. Multiply that by 1000000 and you get 4081200, then they subtracted a million.

Comment: I set a new projection string: tmpShape.ProjectionString = +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs.